# Pattern matching and String Manipulation in R

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching

Here's the article data I have.

#

```
inp <- Sentence1+sentence2+.......+ LAST SENTENCE OF THE ARTICLE+A version of this article appears in print on 08/05/2015, on page C3 of the....
```

I would like to do two things.

First, I would like to **get rid of all of the sentences *from*** "A version of this article appears in print".

Second, I would like to extract the **C3** in the "A version of this article appears in print on 08/05/2015, on page **C3**" sentence.

I tried to do these with str_replace_all function, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test case:

```
art <- "Sentence1+sentence2+.......+ LAST SENTENCE OF THE ARTICLE+ A version of this article appears in print on 08/05/2015, on page C3 of the Archive copy. The archive can be fouund here, blah, blah. And more blah, blah, blah."
```

First remove undesired material up to the page ref (including the space after "page"). We are assuming that all articles have a date in dd/nn/YYYY format;

```
> pgref <- gsub("^.+appears\\ in\\ print\\ on\\ \\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}.+page\\ ", "", art)
> pgref
[1] "C3 of the Archive copy. The archive can be fouund here, blah, blah. And more blah, blah, blah."
> pgref <- gsub("\\ .+$", "", pgref)
> pgref
[1] "C3"
```

Then move on to remove the trailing stuff:

```
> trimart <- gsub("A version of this article\\ appears\\ in\\ print\\ on\\ \\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}.+$", "", art)
> trimart
[1] "Sentence1+sentence2+.......+ LAST SENTENCE OF THE ARTICLE+ "
```

Comment: Thanks! it works pretty well!

Comment: Then where's the checkmark? (You are too new to upvote I think.) I voted to reopen since I thought it was a sufficiently clear question and only required minimal extra coding to build an answer.